# Connected devices for debuggin does not show up in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to debug my code on the connected devices (iPad and Android tablet), however I only see the Virtual Devices installed:

[image]

---

- I'm using Xamarin on Mac OS X El Capitan.
- The USB debugging is enabled on the Android Tablet.
- OS can detect the connected devices.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did the device ever ask you if the computer you were going to debug from should be trusted? You might try revoking USB debugging authorizations (on device settings, Developer options)? Then when you connect, expect to get the prompt, and allow the trust, and for convenience, check the box to always trust your computer.

Comment: The source of the problem was something not related to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem was the USB cables for some reason. They could charge the device, but Mac wasn't detecting it.

I changed the USB cable and restarted Xamarin Studio, resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Information Mac OS X app, go to USB tab and try to find your device in list.

If you see device, do it:

1) check xamarin updates and install fresh version.

2) check your project settings

3) check last updates of android sdk/build tools (you must install last versions and remove old versions)

4) restart Mac OS X

last advice resolve problem in my case.

Answer (score -1):

*On device:*

1. Developer options → **ON**
2. Developer options → USB debugging → **ON**

   [image]
3. Developer options → Select USB Configuration → **MTP**

   [image]